# Link one table to another?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-express

i'm trying to set up some tables in my SQL Express server, and i want to do something to the effect of this:

```
create table programs (
    progid int primary key identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(255),
    description nvarchar(500),
    iconFile nvarchar(255),
    installScript nvarchar(255)
)
```

however i want each "program" to have a set of categories associated with it, what's the best way to do this? i read somewhere that it's not a good idea to store multiple items under a single category entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another table for categories like this:

```
create table categories(
   catid int not null primary key identity,
   caterogy varchar(255) not null
)
```

then store categories related to program using third table:

```
create table progcategory(
    progid int foreign key references programs(progid) not null,
    catid int foreign key references categories(catid) not null,
    primary key(progid, catid)
)
```

Comment: I was just about to ask where the pk was =)

Comment: If i understand this then, each program can only be in one category?

Comment: @RCIX: No, the pk is a composite key.  It means that there can only be one combination of a given program to a given category.  In other words, it stops someone from associating "banana" to a specific program more than once.

Comment: ohhhh.... i get it now. So you can have a program in there with the categories A B and C? this should work nicely. Thanks!

Comment: @RCIX: Yes, exactly.  If A, B, and C categories are associated, it won't let you add another A, B or C for that program only.

Answer (score 3):

First, define a table (assuming you haven't already) to contain the list of categories with id and value columns at a minimum.

Can a program be associated to only one category?  If yes, add a column to the PROGRAMS table and create a foreign key reference between the category column in PROGRAMS to the id column in the CATEGORIES table.

If you want to be able to associate one or more categories to a program, you'll need an additional table:

`PROGRAM_CATEGORIES_XREF`:

- PROG_ID (pk, fk)
- CATEGORY_ID (pk, fk)

In this case, you won't need to add a column to the PROGRAMS table because of the link between the PROG_ID columns.